# Titanium remote images initial run

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

My issue: 
I want my application to have an initial data set, including images, for the first run.

But after that if the user connects to the internet, they can download newer images.

From what i can google, the way to do that is to use image caching.

How do i do initial caching of the images for the first run on the application? (if the application runs offline the first time)

Comment: Well at this moment nothing. Here's my dilemma. If we're talking about caching images, how do i pre-cache the images for a first run as a packaged application?

Answer (score 0):

You can put initial files inside your project and Titanium will include them during build process. To update them in the future you have to use [`Titanium.Filesystem.File`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File) object.